# Interacting with FRM network contract using web3.py

Tags: web3.py, python

I am trying to call a function on a contract on the FTM network using web3.py.  My code runs, and the final call to sendRawTransaction returns a tx id, but it never makes it to any of the nodes.  Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
from web3 import Web3

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://rpc.ftm.tools/'))
w3.eth.blockNumber # Test, successful

my_addy = w3.toChecksumAddress('0xxxx')

contract_addy = w3.toChecksumAddress('0xxxx')

abi = '''xxx'''

contract = w3.eth.contract(contract_addy, abi=abi)

signed_txn = w3.eth.account.signTransaction({
    'nonce':w3.eth.get_transaction_count(my_addy)+ 3,
    'from':my_addy,
    'to':caddy,
    'gas':98340,
    'gasPrice':Web3.toWei(106.3613, "gwei"),
    'value':Web3.toWei(0, "ether"),
    'data': contract.encodeABI(fn_name="funcation_name", args=[123]),
    'chainId':250,
  },
  'XXprivate_keyXX'
)    

x = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)

> x # tx id is being returned, but never makes to a node
HexBytes('0x4xxxxxxx6')
```

Comment: Why are you using `w3.eth.get_transaction_count(my_addy)+ 3` to set the nonce?

Comment: oops, that's supposed to be +1 -- cut and paste fail when removing private info from gist.  (is +1 correct?)

Comment: In most cases `'nonce':w3.eth.get_transaction_count(my_addy)` should work. If you don't have any pending transaction `get_transaction_count` returns the next nonce.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm having issues with send_raw_transaction function on fantom as well?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using build transaction?

```
contract = w3.eth.contract(contract_addy, abi=abi)

function_txn = contract.functions.**functionname**(
**kwargs
).buildTransaction({
    'nonce':w3.eth.get_transaction_count(my_addy, 'pending'),
    'from':my_addy,
    'to':caddy,
    'gas':98340,
    'gasPrice':Web3.toWei(106.3613, "gwei"),
    'value':Web3.toWei(0, "ether"),
    'chainId':250
  })    

signed_txn = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(function_txn,'XXprivate_keyXX')
x = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```